# Wrong value of variable in AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, json

I have a bit of code that uses JSON to check vat numbers.

I need to know which VAT numbers are correct

```
BTW[0] = 'NL1234567890';
BTW[1] = 'NL1233537891';
BTW[2] = 'NL1232346894';

var arraylength = BTW.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
  
 var BTWnummer = BTW[i];
 
 callUrl = 'http://isvat.appspot.com/'+Land+'/'+BTWnummer+'/?callback=?';
 
 $.getJSON(callUrl, BTWnummer, function(data){
 alert(data+' '+BTWnummer);
 
 });
 
}
```

The data variable returns true or false. But I can't get the right BTWnummer inside the function that returns from the JSON. It always keeps 1 BTW number. I think JSON is asynchronous, so how can I get the right number inside the bit of JSON code? According to my tests It does use the different numbers in the callUrl.

Comment: Country code,  its included in a variable from a dropdown. In this instance NL (not every VAT number starts with country code, or users forget to add that).

Comment: You should probably have `var ` in front of `callUrl`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `BTWnummer` has changed when the callback is called because the loop is entirely executed before the asynchronous callbacks.

You may save its value in an immediately called function :

```
for (var i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
   (function(BTWnummer){
      var callUrl = 'http://isvat.appspot.com/'+Land+'/'+BTWnummer+'/?callback=?';
      $.getJSON(callUrl, BTWnummer, function(data){
         alert(data+' '+BTWnummer);
      });
   })(BTW[i]);
}
```

If it's hard to read, here's another way to put it with a named function (instead of an anonymous one) :

```
function f(BTWnummer){
  var callUrl = 'http://isvat.appspot.com/'+Land+'/'+BTWnummer+'/?callback=?';
  $.getJSON(callUrl, BTWnummer, function(data){
     alert(data+' '+BTWnummer);
  });
}
for (var i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
    f(BTW[i]);
}
```

This works because the scope of a variable in JavaScript is the function execution. Different executions of `f` store different values of `BTWnummer` (look for "closure" to go deeper).

In the near future with ES6, this trick won't be needed any more as the `let` keyword will define variables whose scope is the block.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work! Can you explain how the latest bit (BTW[i]); works? It is outside the function, but still works?

Comment: Ah yes! I did now know you could write unnamed functions with parameters like that.

Comment: Hmmm, somehow it always returns true right now. It did seem to work for a second. Didn't change the code. But I think thats problem lies with the URL im calling.

Comment: What do you mean it "returns" true ? Where does it return something ?

Comment: http://isvat.appspot.com/ the data variable returns true or false. Right now even if I input a faulty VAT number it always returns true. Im currently testing what is causing this. Trying to make a jsfiddle, but it seems to be down.